# How to create a metric alert in Azure that only fires during a specified timeframe?

Tags: azure

I have a logic app set up that so that when a file is received on the FTP it gets put into the blob. The file is coming from a third party and it will be coming (supposedly) by 4am every morning. I want to set up an alert to know if the file didn't get received by 4am.

I've gone through all the different types of alerts and triggers, but I can't seem to figure out how to make one trigger when an event DOESN'T happen. I also can't figure out how to make the alert only check for a certain timeframe. I'm thinking I'm going to have to make my own alert by adding an action onto the logic app, but I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box I don't think it's possible.

You could create a simple BlobTrigger Azure Function that when the file is changed/uploaded, the function will fire. When the function fires you can write a custom metric to app insights that you can then query on in the alert.

Comment: I dont have any evidence to back this up, but I do agree with this answer

Comment: Thanks. It was a slim hope there was something built in that i just hadn't discovered.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue:

So I set up a logic app with a recurrence of 4am every day. It sets a flag variable to false, then lists every blob within the folder the blobs are coming in to. It checks every blob in it to see if the last modified date is today (the folder gets emptied daily with another logic) If it finds one it sets the flag as true and then nothing happens. If it doesn't the flag is still false so it sends an email saying the file was not sent today.